# Using TFL api - C# on the backend and React.js on the front end

Tags: c#, .net, reactjs, api

I'm trying to improve my C# and React skills so I am creating a small web app that shows the status of the London Underground lines using the TFL api: https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Line/Mode/tube/Status

I have a controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace TFL.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class TubeApi : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetTubeStatus()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.tfl.gov.uk");
                    var response = await client.GetAsync("/Line/Mode/tube/Status");
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    var stringResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    var rawData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(stringResult);

                        return Ok(new
                        {
                            LineId = rawData.name
                        });

                }
                catch (HttpRequestException httpRequestException)
                {
                    return BadRequest("Error getting data");
                }
            }
        }

    }


    public class RootObject
    {
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string name { get; set; }
        public List<LineStatus> lineStatuses { get; set; }

    }

    public class LineStatus
    {
        public string statusSeverityDescription { get; set; }

    }

}
```

And I have the front end:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            tube: "",
            status: ""
        };
    }

    getData(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        fetch("api/TubeApi/GetTubeStatus")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data =>
                this.setState({
                    tube: data.TubeLine,
                    status: data.TubeStatus
                })
            );
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <center>
                    <h1>Tube</h1>
                    <h4>Name</h4>
                    <p>{this.state.tube}</p>
                    <h4>Status</h4>
                    <p>{this.state.status}</p>

                </center>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

My aim is to make the two interact so that the front end is pulling data from the controller that I have created. However, the data is not pulling through :(

I have tried switching up the controller routing and changed the names to match what they do in the Json but this does not work. I am new to this so I am probably missing something very obvious and would appreciate any pointers in the right direction please.

**EDIT/UPDATE**

The API endpoint returns an array so I have updated to deserialize a list. However, this still is not working and this time also throws build errors (saying that RootObject does not contain a definition for name).

Comment: We need more information, please check if the requests are actually being sent and if so, what are they returning?

Comment: Hi @Bassie thanks - how can I check this?

Comment: You dont need to write JS code to test a GET request, simply type in your browser localhost:xxxx/api/TubeApi/GetTubeStatus and check if your endpoint is being called and what is the response. Replace xxxx by whatever port your server is running on.

Comment: Thank you @Philippe - it doesn't seem like it's being sent as when I make that get request, I get a blank page. However, when I type in localhost:xxxx/api/TubeApi I get the following error "JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'TFL.Controllers.TubeResponse' because the type requires a JSON object "

Comment: Did you check how the response from https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Line/Mode/tube/Status looks like in you browser? Simply install a JSON formatting extension, for example JSONView in chrome. This endpoint returns an array but your .Net code attempts to deserialize it into an object.... solve the pb you have on your backend first, otherwise there is no chance you can successfully call that endpoint from your client.

Comment: @juemura7 1. Please set some breakpoints in your controller and see if they get hit when the api gets called 2. go into devtools (F12) and check the network tab when the request fires. You should see it listed there and then you can check the code/response etc

Comment: Thanks @Philippe, i can see the problem now and have been trying to solve it this morning. I will update my code with what I have tried - do you know why this isn't working?